# SQL Query For Graph Like Table

Tags: sql, hana

Graph can be represented using vertex and edge table .

Vertex holds nodes details and edge holds the relationship .

```
    VERTEX                        EDGE
    ------                       ----------------------------
     ID                           ID    |  Source   | Target
    ------                       ----------------------------
     A                            1        A            B
     B                            2        A            B
     C                            3        B            C
     D                            4        B            D
     E                            5        D            B
                                  6        A            D
                                  7        B            A
                                  8        E            A
```

Graph :

[image]

I am trying to get direct neighbor of each node using SQL query .

```
 OUTPUT
---------------------------
ID    | COUNT
---------------------------
 A        3
 B        3
 C        1
 D        2
 E        1
```

Explanation :

A has connection to E , D , B

B has connection to C, A, D

Comment: Why don’t you use the graph engine build into HANA to solve this? Seems like a good fit to me...

Comment: I am looking if that is possible using SQL ? Using graph engine is advanced solution , looking for some basic solution .

Comment: For this problem the SQL will be a lot more advanced than the graph engine... but hey, your call. Joe Celko has some books covering how to handle graphs in SQL. That’ll work on HANA too.

Comment: I was thinking it could be simple as I am looking for one level only

Comment: Post the edge table example - then it should be easy to do the immediate neighbors.

Comment: I have posted both edge and vertex table on question starting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add this variant:

```
select source, count(distinct target) 
from
    (select  source, target 
    from edge e_out
    union all
    select  target, source -- note the switch of src/trgt columns
    from edge e_in)
group by source
order by source;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check following SQL query giving the exact result you are looking for

```
select
    Vertex.ID,
    Count(Neighbour) as "Count"
from GraphVertex as Vertex
left join (
select
    v.ID,
    e.Target as Neighbour
from GraphVertex as v
inner join GraphEdge as e
    on v.ID = e.Source

union

select
    v.ID,
    e.Source as Neighbour
from GraphVertex as v
inner join GraphEdge as e
    on v.ID = e.Target
) as Neighbours
    on Vertex.ID = Neighbours.ID
group by Vertex.ID
order by Vertex.ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

although you have named your tables as Vertex and Edge all solutions provided here seem to be SQLScript solutions instead of a Graph language solution.

I tried to create a Graph database solution for your request, but I had a few difficulties that I had to overcome.

First, since I am new to Graph I could not find a direct solution. You know Edge's are directed records. But your question wants total number of neighbors in both directions. So I had to dublicate the rows by cross-changing the source and target columns.

Then I used following procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE graphProcedureSample2(in ID varchar(2), out cnt int)
LANGUAGE GRAPH READS SQL DATA AS
BEGIN
    Graph g = Graph("A00077387", "SAMPLEGRAPHWORKSPACE");
    cnt = 0;
    Vertex v = Vertex(:g, :ID);
    Multiset<Vertex> neighbors = NEIGHBORS (:g, :v, 1, 1);
    Multiset<Edge> edges = EDGES (:g, :v, :neighbors);
    cnt = INT(COUNT(:neighbors));
END;
```

But above code works only for a single vertex.

[image]

I had to [create HANA database cursor](http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/sap-hana-database-sqlscript-cursor-sample.aspx) and loop through all vertices then call this SP for each.

I have stored the results in a temp table and got the result you requested by querying this temp table.

I hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

```
select a, count(*) as connections from
(
    select a, b from
    (
        select Source a, Target b from EDGE
        union
        select Target a, Source b from EDGE
    ) group by a,b
) group by a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Source < Target THEN Source ELSE Target END AS Node1,
       CASE WHEN Source >= Target THEN Source ELSE Target END AS Node2
FROM EDGE
```

to get:

```
Node1   Node2
-------------
A       B
A       B
B       C
B       D
B       D
A       D
A       B
A       E
```

This is a simplified, stripped down, version of the `EDGE` table, that contains  only node connection information.

You can further strip down using `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       CASE WHEN Source < Target THEN Source ELSE Target END AS Node1,
       CASE WHEN Source >= Target THEN Source ELSE Target END AS Node2
FROM EDGE
```

so that duplicates are removed:

```
Node1   Node2
-------------
A       B
A       D
A       E
B       C
B       D
```

You can now wrap the above query in a `CTE`, unpivot and then count:

```
;WITH SimpleEDGE AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
           CASE WHEN Source < Target THEN Source ELSE Target END AS Node1,
           CASE WHEN Source >= Target THEN Source ELSE Target END AS Node2
    FROM EDGE
)
SELECT Node, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM (
    SELECT Node1 AS Node
    FROM SimpleEDGE

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Node2 AS Node
    FROM SimpleEDGE
) AS t
GROUP BY Node
```

**Output:**

```
Node    cnt
-----------
A       3
B       3
C       1
D       2
E       1
```